# IF infant missed the now() date schedule then he we will get the show next date schedule php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

IF the infant id missed the now() date schedule then we will get the show next date schedule
This is my database table:
[image]

code:

```
<?php
// Set the new timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$date = date("Y-m-d");
//$date = '2022-06-09';
//echo $date;
//$tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"));
//echo $tomorrow;
?>
        <div class="card-body">
         <div class="table-responsive" id="dynamic_content">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Infant ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Mother Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Child Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">DOB</th>
                    <th scope="col">Schedule Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Visit Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Visit Status</th>
                    <th scope="col">Serv Diag</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    //$query="SELECT * FROM `infant_schedule` WHERE Visit_Status=0 AND ('".$date."' OR '".$tomorrow."' ) between Schedule_date and Visit_date"; 
                    $query="SELECT * FROM `infant_schedule` WHERE Visit_Status=0 AND '".$date."' between Schedule_date and Visit_date"; 
 
                    if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
                    <td><input type="text" name="Infant_id" value="<?php echo $row['Infant_id'];?>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Mother_Name" value="<?php echo $row['Mother_Name'];?>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Child_Name" value="<?php echo $row['Child_Name'];?>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="DOB" value="<?php echo $row['DOB'];?>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Schedule_date" value="<?php echo $row['Schedule_date'];?>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Visit_date" value="<?php echo $row['Visit_date'];?>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Visit_Status" value="<?php echo $row['Visit_Status'];?>"readonly></td>
                    <!--<td><select name="Serv_Diag" id="Serv_Diag">
                        <option value="No">Yes</option>
                        <option value="">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>-->
                    <td><input type="text" name="Serv_Diag" value="<?php echo $row['Serv_Diag'];?>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" id="nursename" name="nursename" value="<?php echo ucwords($_settings->userdata('username')) ?>"></td>
                    <td><input class="btn btn-primary edit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                    </form>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                             }
                        }
                             } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
          </div>
```

if infant id missed the visit date=2022-06-05 he will get the show next date schedule list.
anyone can help me, please